# python requests ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to connect to host via ssl using requests module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

But my code:

```
import requests
requests.get("myurl", cert="hosts_certificate_file.crt")
```

throws this error:

```
_ssl.c:364: error:140B0002:SSL  routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
```

I tried to pass `verify=False` to `requests.get()`, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Do you want to connect to a server that requires a client certificate? Try to specify the full path to the client certificate and check that the file contains both cert., private key in pem format.

Comment: Thanks, J.F.Sebastian. I don't have client sertificate, and browser successfully gets response from this server WITHOUT client sertificate. Any advice how to achieve it from within Python script?

Comment: then remove `cert` option and post the errors that you get (with/without `verify=False`)